# Spring Initializr pane is blank in IntellJ, for both New Project and New Module

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, ide

In Intellij, the Spring initializr option is available, but the pane where the options for adding dependencies reside is blank. I tried upgrading my IDE to no avail. This is true when either creating a new project or a new module. This was not an issue until my work issued me a PowerMac (was on Windows before).

When I try to access Initializr, idea.log shows the following stacktrace:

```
2019-02-12 13:52:16,116 [7322253]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - java.lang.NullPointerException 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1488)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:3018)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:489)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.openConnection(HttpRequests.java:609)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$300(HttpRequests.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getConnection(HttpRequests.java:378)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getInputStream(HttpRequests.java:387)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getReader(HttpRequests.java:405)
    at com.intellij.spring.boot.initializr.SpringInitializrOptionsLoader$1.process(SpringInitializrOptionsLoader.java:104)
    at com.intellij.spring.boot.initializr.SpringInitializrOptionsLoader$1.process(SpringInitializrOptionsLoader.java:97)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:523)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:499)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:352)
    at com.intellij.spring.boot.initializr.SpringInitializrOptionsLoader.loadOptions(SpringInitializrOptionsLoader.java:97)
    at com.intellij.spring.boot.initializr.SpringInitializrApplicationInfoStep.lambda$loadSpringInitializrOptions$3(SpringInitializrApplicationInfoStep.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.security.ntlm.Client.type3(Client.java:161)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthentication.buildType3Msg(NTLMAuthentication.java:241)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthentication.setHeaders(NTLMAuthentication.java:216)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2096)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    ... 20 more
```

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)?

Comment: Yes! I edited the question and added a stack trace. NPE was thrown when trying to access SpringInitializr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [Java bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148367) specific to your NTLM proxy.

It may help if you use [IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) version with JetBrains Runtime **11** version where this issue should be fixed.

Comment: My IDE is installed by a remote service managed by my work and I cannot get the EAP version. However this is not a blocker as I can just create a project at start.spring.io, and I can create maven modules instead (which I just found is actually quicker and easier)